# How to print value from previous group?

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping

I have repeated values, I would like them not be printed inside single group, but be printed in the first row of the next group.

```
<group name="userNameGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{userName}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

As far as `userNameGroup` changes I would like first row of the new group to print all values. I set to City, Street, UserName elements `isPrintRepeatedValues="false"`

*Example of current behavior:*

**City**    |    **Street** | **UserName** | **Appointment Date**

```
Minsk | Center street | Janka Kupala | 03-01-2017  
                                       05-07-2017  
                        Jakub Kolas  | 11-08-2017
```

*Example of desirable behavior:*

```
Minsk | Center street | Janka Kupala | 03-01-2017  
                                       05-07-2017  
Minsk | Center street | Jakub Kolas  | 11-08-2017
```

Is it achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can guess on your report structure, you can add a `printWhenGroupChanges=userNameGroup` for City, Street `textFields`.

Comment: And for the UserName textField as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<reportElement printWhenGroupChanges="userNameGroup"/>
```

Does what you need.